# How to centrally align the labels on Value Axis with tick marks

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I am making bar chart in Excel but struggling to keep my labels centrally aligned to tick marks on the Value Axis.

[image]

Is there any property which can be used to achieve this alignment in Excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So did not change the color of the  tick marks but they are central, showing the axis settings as well:

[image]

So, produced a bar chart as asked:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to check with bar chart and with tick marks placed outside of the line. I think you can notice the alignment issue on bar chart.

Comment: @Alok looks like the numbers line up with the gridlines very neatly... You should check your formatting.

Comment: I noticed that I have  VBA code .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "# ### ### ##0" which is causing this , is there a way to ensure proper alignment irrespective of magnitude of the numbers. Thanks

Comment: Also can the alignment be ensured for all cases like negative numbers, small numbers with or without decimals and large numbers with thousand separators. Thanks

Comment: I don't have the time to do an example for every variety of chart possible, also you don't mention any form of vba code in your original question, so I won't be attempting any more.